# AJAX contact form with Validation Engine - jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I tried to make an contact form via AJAX with jQuery and Validation Engine Plug in http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

The validation worked and before to send function worked too... but

The problem is that it cannot send form and it couldn't callback from `OnAjaxFormComplete` that it will "hide" the form using jQuery. It's used for development.

Go to http://bksn.mx/TAC/2/ click "Contacto" big title, it appears a contact form, try it.

My HTML of form:

```
    <form id="formID" method="post" action="submit.php">
<div class="ajax">
        <div class="idealWrap">
            <label for="nombre">nombre:</label>
            <input value="" class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"/>
        </div>

        <div class="idealWrap">
            <label for="email">email:</label>
            <input value="" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
        </div>

        <div class="idealWrap">
            <label for="tel">teléfono:</label>
            <input value="" class="validate[custom[phone]] text-input" type="text" name="tel" id="tel" />
        </div>



        <div class="idealWrap">
            <label for="mensaje">mensaje:</label>
            <textarea value="" class="validate[required] text-input" name="message" id="message" ></textarea>
        </div>      

        <div class="idealWrap">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value=""/>
        </div>
</div>
    </form>
```

There is my script:

```
function beforeCall(form, options) {
    if (window.console)
        alert("Right before the AJAX form validation call");
    return true;
}

// Called once the server replies to the ajax form validation request

function ajaxValidationCallback(status, form, json, options) {
    if (window.console)
        console.log(status);

    if (status === true) {
        $('#formID').hide();
        // uncomment these lines to submit the form to form.action
        // form.validationEngine('detach');
        // form.submit();
        // or you may use AJAX again to submit the data
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#formID").validationEngine({
        promptPosition: 'centerRight',
        scroll: false,
        ajaxFormValidation: true,
        onBeforeAjaxFormValidation: beforeCall,
        onAjaxFormComplete: ajaxValidationCallback,
    });
});
```

and my PHP script:

```
<?php
$aviso = "";
if ($_POST['email'] != "") {
    // email de destino
    $email = "vagnok@gmail";

    // asunto del email
    $subject = "Contacto";

    // Cuerpo del mensaje
    $mensaje = "---------------------------------- \n";
    $mensaje.= "            Contacto               \n";
    $mensaje.= "---------------------------------- \n";
    $mensaje.= "NOMBRE:   ".$_POST['nombre']."\n";
    $mensaje.= "EMAIL:    ".$_POST['email']."\n";
    $mensaje.= "TELEFONO: ".$_POST['tel']."\n";
    $mensaje.= "FECHA:    ".date("d/m/Y")."\n";
    $mensaje.= "HORA:     ".date("h:i:s a")."\n";
    $mensaje.= "IP:       ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n\n";
    $mensaje.= "---------------------------------- \n\n";
    $mensaje.= $_POST['mensaje']."\n\n";
    $mensaje.= "---------------------------------- \n";
    $mensaje.= "Enviado desde TAC  \n";

    // headers del email
    $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";

    // Enviamos el mensaje
    if (mail($email, $subject, $mensaje, $headers)) {
        $aviso = "Su mensaje fue enviado.";
    } else {
        $aviso = "Error de envío.";
    }
}
 ?>
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `echo json_encode($aviso);` to the end of your PHP file.. your not posting anything back :)

Comment: It didn't work :(, i wonder how to get a callback after of "OnAjaxComplete"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read and tried the FAQ on github: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine ? There is a part where it says:

> When using options, the default behavior is to only initialize
>   ValidationEngine, **so attachment needs to be done manually**.
>
> ```
> <script>
> $(document).ready(function(){
> $("#formID").validationEngine('attach', {promptPosition : "centerRight", scroll: false});
> });
> </script>
> ```

In the code posted above you aren't supplying any action as parameter. If you use any options for validationEngine you have to use **"attach" as first parameter** to enable the plugin to work!

Your code should look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#formID").validationEngine('attach', {
        promptPosition: 'centerRight',
        scroll: false,
        ajaxFormValidation: true,
        onBeforeAjaxFormValidation: beforeCall,
        onAjaxFormComplete: ajaxValidationCallback,
    });
});
```

Comment: I added "attach" but it didn't callback from "OnAjaxComplete" :( yes i read manual but it looks complex to me...

Comment: Actually, i moved files to real server, it seems worked... but it didn't send email

Comment: Sorry, this didn't help, i am not familiar with the plugin. That was what i've seen directly after taking a look into to the documentation :-)

Comment: Yeah I just tried it. The data I entered was sent, however your server returned an empty string. You should check again your php for sending the e-mail. The jquery part now seems fine.

Comment: Your answer was helpful, but i want this function should to work at 100%, i'm experimenting... i really love if you should to show source codes how it works, im justw asting my time :/

Comment: I 'd really love to help you, but I am a littly busy too.
Btw you've forgotten to add the domain name at the end of the e-mail adress. it should be
    $email = "vagnok@gmail.com";

You should also check the comments section on:
http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php

Comment: No problem, whenever you have a chance, i will wait :)