# Not able to call a jquery function in a ajax returned code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am not much of a javascript programmer, I am learning so please forgive the stupid mistakes.

I am trying to save customer details using ajax (its not the jquery ajax), which returns another form for advanced details. I am using a jquery plugin for validation of input boxes. But the validation doesn't work on the form returned by ajax.

Ajax code:

```
function createcustomer() {
    var firstname = _("firstname").value;
    var lastname = _("lastname").value;
    var email = _("email").value;
    var phone = _("phone").value;
    var status = _("status");
    if (firstname == "" || lastname == "" || email == "" || phone == "") {
        status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else {
        _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "save-customer.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {

                if (ajax.responseText != "failure") {
                    _("signupform").innerHTML = "";

                    _("advancedform").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;


                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    _("signupform").innerHTML = "Error Occured";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone);
    }

}

function ajaxObj(meth, url) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(meth, url, true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}

function ajaxReturn(x) {
    if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have tested the ajax return code thouroughly and the jquery works independently on that form.
This is how I initiate the jquery validation plugin :

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $('form').validationEngine();
});
```

I tried putting the exact code in the createcustomer() function to reload the jquery function but it doesnt work. Is there any way I can call that jquery validation function in the ajax function?
Any help will be appreciated.

Regards
Priyanshu

Comment: this is likely because the element doesn't exist when you try to call `validationEngine()` instead add `$('form').validationEngine();` inside your `success` for your ajax call.  You can't `bind` events to dom elements that don't exists...unless you use `.on` which this add-on likely isn't

Comment: If you have jQuery, you might consider using the `$.ajax()`, if this is just a "learning exercise" then so be it, it then would almost smell like homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm suspecting that your validation is trying to find a form that doesnt exists at the execution time, try putting the validation binding when you have sure that the form exists in your DOM. To achieve this you should put the validation binder:

```
$('form').validationEngine();
```

...inside the callback after the ajax loads some HTML data in the document. Like this:

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {

        if(ajax.responseText != "failure"){
            _("signupform").innerHTML = "";

            _("advancedform").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            $('#ajaxreturnform').validationEngine('attach'); //Here

        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
            _("signupform").innerHTML = "Error Occured";
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked around here and found this post [Attach Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912735/ajax-contact-form-with-validation-engine-jquery) the accepted answer may inlight your problem also. Try to put the 'attach' command as a parameter to your binder as well as the #id of your form.

Comment: agreed, i believe this to be a dom element binding issue. please describe why this is an issue if this ends up solving the issue for him.

Comment: I've updated the solution, see if providing 'attach' command resolves

Comment: Well do you think is possible to put your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ to me take a look?

Comment: Is it possible?? I mean I have a php file, few css files and the jquery files, is there a way to upload the files ?

Comment: Hey Roger, I have managed to somehow eliminate the php and ajax from the code and put it on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/XhGKz/3/
But for some reasons its not loading the code from javascript on jsfiddle, same code works fine on my system( except for the jquery plugin). Please take a look if possible.

Comment: Updated the code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XhGKz/4/,
This recreates the exact situation I am facing.

Comment: Added the $('#ajaxreturnform').validationEngine('attach') at the end of 'Simulated' situation and worked follows the Link: http://jsfiddle.net/XhGKz/5/

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems that validation only applies for the first form element that is returned by the selector

Comment: Its working for all the elements. It works like charm. Thank You Thank You So much Roger. Perfect Answer.